# List items in CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using an instance of CKEditor 4.5.7 that should not allow any `<p />` tags.
The config looks like this:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.forceEnterMode = true;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

Now, when I insert an ordered `<ol />` or unordered `<ul />` list, I cannot add a second list item because pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> only adds a `<br />` inside the `<li />` instead of adding a new `<li />`.

I would like the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a new `<li />`, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a `<br />` inside the `<li />`.

Only when I change the `enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_P`, I can add new `<li />` items, but then the user can add `<p />` tags everywhere.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, **using `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` [is not recommended](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_best_practices-section-use-enter-mode-p)** and may cause some editor features not to work as expected. If you do it to control paragraph spacing, you should use stylesheets instead.

In your particular case, however, check whether you really need to set [`config.forceEnterMode`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-forceEnterMode) to `true` as this seems to be causing your issue.

Take a look at the [Enter Key Configuration](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/enterkey.html) sample - with both `config.enterMode` and `config.shiftEnterMode` set to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` it works just as you want it, with <kbd>Enter</kbd> creating new list items and <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> creating a `<br />` inside the list item.

Comment: That helped - I also found the related bug report here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14331